# Does it make sense to use an input object as a parameter to a graphQL query(not mutation)

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, graphql-java

I am designing a graphQL service and looked at input objects and recommendations regarding using them for mutations. Does it also make sense to use input objects as parameter(s) to query if number of parameters is large(lets assume around 10 for the discussion)? Why? Why not?

Also, if it makes sense to use input objects for queries what should be considered to figure out if it is a right solution for me?

example query:

````
  retrieveData(
    ids: [ID!]
    codes: [String!]
    countries: [String!]
    types: [String!]
    business: [String!]
    locations: [ID!]
    region: Region!
    limit: Int = 50
    offset: Int = 0
    sortBy: SortBy
    version: Int
  ): Response!```
````

Comment: no, amount is not the reason, similarity is the key (f.e. pagination - limit+offset) ... `retrieveData` looks like no specific type ... properties looks like relations embedded in type ... `where`-like filtering could be used

Comment: I intentionally renamed the query just to make it generic. @xadm You are right that these are parameters used for filtering the data returned. All the parameters till locations are being used for filtering and are part of the response object. They can be combined in an input object like DataFilter and we can have another input object for Pagination. What would be the downsides of such approach?

Comment: properties/filters still 'looks like relations embedded in type', name doesn't make a difference ... no downsides